# Display divs horizontally with css

Tags: css, html

I'm new to web design and I try with several ways to put my button `<div>`s in one `<div>` horizontally. I tried using `display:inline-block` and `float:left` but neither worked. Please can somebody tell me what is the error [there](http://jsfiddle.net/wZf4C):

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wZf4C/1/

Comment: Please post your problem code as well as jsFiddle links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: what i need is to put first 3 buttons (repin,like,comment) horizobtally and second 3 buttons the same way to be horizontally

Comment: the link is in comment becouse I get some error when i put in on question. Thanks, and sorry for my english

Comment: First step: VASTLY simplify your CSS. you've got a zillion rules in there. And your HTML is highly invalid. you've got extra spans, spans that straddle other elements, etc..

Comment: I can't becouse I buy an script with this code and now only I need one modification - to put buttons horizontally

Comment: here is simplified css: http://jsfiddle.net/wZf4C/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yowza! First rule of debugging: simplify your conditions. You have tons of CSS packed into that fiddle, which makes it tricky for anyone to zero in on your problem.

You have two things preventing your buttons from appearing on the same line horizontally.

```
.pin .actions {
    width: 125px;
}
```

This made the container too narrow to fit more than one button per line. Try changing that to 300px. (Or, you know, anything bigger.)

```
.actions .WhiteButton.Button11 {
    clear: both;
}
```

This style means that no floated items are permitted either to the right or the left of the button.

Change both of these and you should have what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/wZf4C/2/

Comment: I'm glad it's working! You should go ahead and accept an answer. I recommend accepting Eamon Nerbonne's, since our answers are the same and Eamon was first.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a `clear:both` statement in there which effectively nullifies your `float:left;`.  Also, your containing div has a tiny 125px size, which is likely too small for your floats to fit.   You could let the container auto-size, and limit the size later on once you get to the graphic design phase.

Also, you've got lots of unnecessary and probably buggy markup in there.  You should consider a systematic rewrite before investing lots of time and money in maintenance.  It's likely you can get the same layout in a much simpler, less error-prone fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.grid{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#666666;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
</style>

<div class="grid">Div 1</div>
<div class="grid">Div 2</div>
<div class="grid">Div 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy css code line solves your problem.

```
maring-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

I use this trick when I want to align `div` or `span` horizontally